# Excluding Tags from Post Title Names

Tags: discussion

A while back, there was a big movement on StackOverflow to remove tags from post title names. I believe that we should be doing the same thing here and I am just wondering if the community agrees with me.

**Examples (not from real posts):**

1. *Indexing - Error when trying to use the Tree Search in the Sitecore UI*
2. *SPEAK - Creating a custom dialog for a custom field*
3. *Solr - Getting an error when trying to reindex with a clean instance*
4. *Sitecore 8 - Multilist with Search field selection pane not populating*

**Side-note:** I haven't seen any situations where this has happened yet, but I just wanted to make sure there is an official decision on this.

**UPDATE:**

Based on @JammyKam's response, I would like to clarify what I mean by "tags in the post titles". What I am referring to is the inclusion of a tag at the beginning or end of a post title, that isn't actually part of the post title. Often times, these tags are separated from the post title using a dash, a pipe, or another special character.

The following (rewrites of the above examples) would be totally acceptable *even if* we say that tags should be excluded from the post title:

1. *Getting index-related error when trying to use the Tree Search in the Sitecore UI*
2. *Creating a custom SPEAK dialog for a custom field*
3. *Getting a Solr error when trying to reindex with a clean instance*

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes tags in titles make sense, especially from an SEO point of view and getting people to the answers they want directly instead of having to look through several posts.

Take your examples for instance:

> Indexing - Error when trying to use the Tree Search in the Sitecore UI

Depending on the context, maybe the title should be *Error with search results when trying to use...*, so maybe [indexing](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) in the title here is good not a idea.

> SPEAK - Creating a custom dialog for a custom field

Maybe the title should be *Creating a custom SPEAK dialog for a custom field*. The older Sheer UI dialogs are still relevant, there are plenty of customers who are still on older versions of Sitecore (esp 7.2). I know if I was creating a dialog then I would use the term SheerUI or SPEAK in my search terms.

> Solr - Getting an error when trying to reindex with a clean instance

I think this would depend entirely on relevancy, if the error is also present in Lucene then would agree that the [solr](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solr) tag in title is not relevant, however if it is SOLR specific then possibly. Neutral on this one, but would reword the title not to start with tag, e.g. *Getting a SOLR error when trying to reindex with a clean instance*

> Sitecore 8 - Multilist with Search field selection pane not populating

Agree the [sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) tag is not relevant here, the version information should be in the question itself.

Not really conclusive I know, but sometimes a tag does add relevancy to a question and sometimes a tag is not really a tag and is just a word, e.g. "Error when indexing large number of items in bucket folder" is not really using the term *indexing* as a tag but it is relevant to describing the issue.

I don't think there is a "one size fits all" that can be blanket applied across all posts.

Comment: I totally agree with you that including it within the context of the title is sometimes needed. My question is more geared at the movement on StackOverflow to remove instances of tags in titles that were not in context, like "Tag - Here is my title". I will update my post to clarify.

Comment: I agree with you on that point, just including it for the sake of including it. There are already a number of posts here that include `Sitecore` in the title, totally pointless (and you're in the wrong place if it is now about Sitecore)

Comment: Just as a note, the most popular tag of the question [**_will_ be included in the page title automatically**](http://i.imgur.com/ZPcsnhu.png).

Comment: Sure, in the browser title, but not in the title of the question, which I presume is what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @jammykam I was referring to this part of your answer: _"Sometimes tags in titles make sense, especially from an SEO point of view"_. I think the SEO aspect is covered by automatically including a tag name in the page title.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO we should do our best to make sure that we keep the titles clear of tag names. The tags are already shown in the listing and the tag names just make the titles longer and harder to read.